# List of cooperative mutli-agent system probem domains

Tags: multi-agent

Is there an online resource that lists cooperative multi-agent system problem domains and perhaps compares them along some dimensions? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resources I found were from the International Planning Competition Domains. These follow different 'tracks' depending on the type of problem:

International Probabilistic Planning Competition Discrete Track:

https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~mgrzes/IPPC_2014/index.html

Probabilistic Planning Competition Continuous Track:

http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~ssanner/IPPC_2014/index.html

Learning Track:

http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~ipc2014/domains.html

Deterministic Track:

https://helios.hud.ac.uk/scommv/IPC-14/domains.html

I also found DEC-POMDP domains here:

http://masplan.org/problem_domains